# Zsh: check existing of file before expanding

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

In Zsh parameter expansion, I have:

```
"${test_var:-"${HOME}/test"}"
```

but here I want to check if `${HOME}/test` is exist or not, if not exist then `test_var` expand to `" "` (one space string).

Is there an inline solution for this?

Comment: And if it exists, what happens ?

Comment: @don_crissti: If `test_var` is not set or null then expand to `${HOME}/test` but if `${HOME}/test` not exist then expand `test_var` to `" "`, if `${HOME}/test` exists then expand `test_var` to `${HOME}/test` as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ${test_var:-~/test(N)}
```

comes close. By adding a `(N)` (and here as we are in list context), that `~/test(N)` becomes a glob, and because of that `N` glob qualifier, if there's no `test` directory entry in `$HOME` (`~`), then the glob expands to nothing.

That's different from what you're asking in that it expands to nothing at all, instead of a one space argument.

For that, you could still do it in to steps:

```
f=(~/test(N)); echo ${test_var:-${f:-' '}}
```

You could also use command substitution, though that's a bit cheating:

```
echo ${test_var:-"${$(printf %s ~/test(N)):-' '}"}
```

Or:

```
echo ${test_var:-"$((){<<<${1-' '}} ~/test(N))"}
```

Comment: How to put `f=(~/test(N)); echo ${test_var:-${f:-' '}}` into position of `~/test(N)` in `echo ${test_var:-~/test(N)}`?